# Setting re-size boundaries

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize, sidebar

I have a horizontally re-sizable side-bar which itself is composed of two sections which are vertically re-sizable (here's how [my-JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T3TJc/1/))

I achieved this by adding divs which act as draggable re-sizing handlers and then I can act on it's mouse events ..

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
  $('#content').css("width",e.pageX+2);
  ('#history').css("left",e.pageX+2);
})
```

Now I wish to apply the following constraints:

1. min width on the side bar, such that I cannot completely collapse the side-bar
2. min and max height on the two sections of the side bar.

These constraints are similar to those in JSFiddle itself ..
Will I have to do this via JavaScript only or is there a way to achieve this via CSS.

Comment: [Math.min](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min), [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) … done.

Comment: @CBroe where do I apply these though ?

Comment: There where you determine the new width and left values …?

Answer (score 0):

i added a new **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/T3TJc/2/)** for you

in your case you have to check the current width and select the min width or height from css

like  this

```
....
var cvmw = parseInt($('#content').css('min-width'));
....
```

and than check if its reached

```
$(document).mousemove(function (e) {
        // get current with
        var w = parseInt($('#content').css("width"));
        // check if with bigger than min-with
        if (w > cvmw) {
            $('#content').css("width", e.pageX + 2);
            $('#history').css("left", e.pageX + 2);
        } else {
            $('#content').css("width", cvmw + 1);
            $('#history').css("left", cvmw + 1);
            $(document).unbind('mousemove');
        }
    })
```

here the changed css, there are some more changes made for each section

```
#content {
    background-color: WhiteSmoke;
    width:75%;
    height: 80%;
    min-width: 100px; /* added this min-width for further actions */
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top:30px;
    bottom: 100px;
}
```

guess you can do some other actions to keep the mouse bind to drag when hovering something like the dragline